# Ubuntu from USB on my office provided laptop

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-7, intel

I want to install Ubuntu from USB on my office provided laptop (I dont have admin rights!). Attached is the screenshot for system information, just in brife: Intel core i7, with win-7 preinstalled and I don't want to use office login (with limited access to system files and folders or even on web browsing!!). Please help me with what version of Ubuntu, where to download, how to install, and any other thing I need to take care so that my system administrator will not get any notification while using the laptop. I am a newbie to Linux, I am aware of how to use is but I not aware of how to install.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24oaf.jpg)

Comment: I think you can get into trouble, if you use the company's computer in a way that is not allowed. A skilled system administrator will see your activities, if you try to connect to the internet via the company's network. You can ask your boss or the system administrator, if it is OK to install and run Ubuntu, and if they say 'yes', fine, there should be no problems. Otherwise you should use another computer for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can understand. I am not using this laptop in office or in office network for my personal use. But when I am free at home I do want to use it. Asking boss is not a good idea for sure. Hence, I asked on the forum.

Comment: If you want no traces in the computer, I suggest that you run Ubuntu completely from USB (without touching the internal drive). You can run a live-only, persistent live or installed system (installed like in the internal drive, but in a USB drive). See this link and links from it, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389. Remove the internal drive before you install Ubuntu. Otherwise the system wants to install the bootloader into the internal drive.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get rid of Windows where you do not have admin rights? If yes, just install linux over and forget about Windows.

However, I do not believe that is what you want to do. My feeling is that for any other scenario you would need some admin rights on Windows:

1. You can shrink Windows partition and install linux on the space freed by that task. Then you can have dual boot. Maybe shrinking can be done with some bootable USB tools.
2. Use VirtualBox or any other software that allows virtual machine and install Linux as a virtual machine within your Windows. I believe you would need admin rights to install such software.
3. You can also boot your linux from USB and use it that way (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/running-linux-usb-right/). Anything on laptop's disk will not be affected by that. However, booting is a bit slower and you are a bit limited with such usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I do not want to get rid of windows. Because when I am working on some office work then I need to use office login (where almost everything is logged!! which scares me a lot). But for my personal use may be using picasa, openoffice and many other things I want to use Ubuntu. (I am freelancing after my work hrs and for that I need to use this laptop.)